# VBA code causing runtime error only in the first time of execution

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, soap-client

Please find the code which is causing run time error during the first time. So the status value is not updated properly.I can see it empty during the first time.

```
Sub test()
Dim http As Object
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "http://localhost:8080/(soap query)", True
http.send
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")
On Error Resume Next
If http.Status <> 200 Then
Debug.Print "no response"
Debug.Print http.Status
End If

Debug.Print "response"
Debug.Print http.Status

End Sub
```

Comment: `http.Open "GET", "http://localhost:8080/(soap query)", True` - use false for the last parameter if you want your code to wait for the response.  What is the error you're getting ?  Also comment out the `On Error Resume Next` since that may be masking something else.

Comment: in order to avoid the run time error to popup I included it. What I could find when i change the true value to false to make it synchronous, application is hanging if my server is starting up.

Comment: Again - what is the error you're getting ?

Comment: If you really want to use async calls then you need something like this: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/09/async-xmlhttp-calls/

Comment: Run-time error'-2147467259 (80004005)'

Comment: Option Explicit
Public xmlHttpRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP    this is giving user-defined type not defined error. Are you aware of that runtime error I mentioned previously.

Comment: What is the **text** of the error message?

Comment: You need to add a reference to the MSXML library to your VBA project

Comment: Once I add the reference it is removed when I close the application. How can I add it permanently.

Comment: The reference should be saved with your workbook - I've not seen that fail.

Comment: error string is "unspecified error"